# How to update Publisher from None to XYZ in VSTO C# Excel 2013 Add-in?

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2013

I have created one Excel 2013 add-ins project using vs2012 vsto with c#.

I have set Publisher name to XXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX Inc. Also I have also added digital signature of my company with same Publisher name to XXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX Inc.

At the time of installation always I get publisher name XXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX Inc. But after installed if I am open Excel's options then Publisher display None

So, please guide me how to update/add publisher name. I have also updated Publish Options but I am not get that in excels options.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is impossible to do with VSTO addins. See:

Saurabh 15 Jan 2014 11:36 AM

> Unfortunately showing the publisher name in the add-ins dialog for VSTO solutions is still not supported. The publisher name only shows up for COM Add-ins.
>
> Its highly unlikely this will change. Since VSTO has its own security/signing which is different from the traditional COM addins the publisher name in the COM addins dialog isn’t populated. The publisher name on the trust prompt when you install the add-in is the main location where it gets displayed to the user and must be trusted in order to run. The publisher name in the COM Addins is merely a string and doesn’t affect the VSTO addins security.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2009/10/19/visual-studio-2010-specify-advanced-publishing-options-saurabh-bhatia.aspx