# Adding a <publisher> to an Excel add-in project

Tags: c#, excel, add-in

I recently had to take over an Excel plugin project and one of the issue I'm getting is that a customer can't use the plugin because their Trust center only allows COM add-ins signed by Trusted publishers. (And they are not able to disable it)

I'm quite new and don't really understand this signing issue so I self-signed the code.

But the add-in has its publisher set to None. Here's how it's showing.

[image: COM add-in menu]

I believe that's not what I need to do, right? As a self signing will not be trusted by the customer Trust Center.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31878184/how-to-update-publisher-from-none-to-xyz-in-vsto-c-sharp-excel-2013-add-in) but I was quite unsure about what was going on.

Does that mean there is no possible workaround or am I getting this wrong?

One thing I was wondering but I needed some help over is that if the add-in needs to be signed by a Trusted publisher.. Would that do the trick if the client is generating .pfx and I use it to sign the add-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there are no "tricks" you can do from the DEV side. This is a security feature. You need to sign your add-in with a valid certificate to get rid of "unknown publisher". You can do that by selecting that certificate on "Sign" tab in Project settings in Visual Studio.

If you are a public company/developer and don't really have any assumptions about your users, then you can obtain the code signing certificate from one of the public code signing certificate providers. The main ones are listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/get-a-code-signing-certificate
It is not free, and you'll need to prove your identity to the certificate issuing authority (like, provide them your passport/company registration details/etc).

If you are developing an add-in for a specific organization and you can negotiate with it's admins, or your users have admin rights on their computers and are allowed to mess with security, then you can create a self-signed certificate, sign your code with it (select it on "Signature" tab), and then ask your users (or user's admin) to add this self-signed certificate to "trusted root" for their organization/on their PC.

Please note that self-signed certificate usually work only on the PC where the certificate was created, and used for testing or development purposes. In your case, this means that your self-signed certificate is considered valid on your PC, but not on the customer's PC. If you want a certificate created by you on your PC to also work on customer's PC, then you'll have to ask the customer to add your certificate as "trusted root", i.e. to treat your signature the same way as one of those "worldwide trusted certification authorities" from the list above.

The normal practice is to buy a certificate from the certification authorities though.

Comment: While the adding to the root would work in theory -- if your client's security requirements are such that they require trusted then I would assume they also can't change the root store.  Otherwise, what is the point?

Comment: @Hogan you are probably right :) if they have "only trusted publishers" option activated then probably they won't allow messing with trusted root. But if the TS works in the same organization that may be okay.. Or they maybe they have in-house trusted certificates.